# What's the mongoid equvilent to COUNT(`column`) in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to count the amount of matching documents with a query using mongoid such as:

```
Chain.where(:updated_at.gte => past_time).count
```

However, I am worried that what's actually happening here is that mongoid is selecting and PARSING everything from mongoid and then returning the count to me. This seems very slow. I want mongo to directly return to me a count, so that ruby/mongoid doesnt have to parse a large amount of objects. In MYSQL I would do this by doing COUNT(`column`), which would spare PHP (for instance) the hassle of parsing/mapping a bunch of rows just to disregard them since I'm only interested in the amount of rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're worrying needlessly. If you check the [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#queries), you'll see that `Criteria#count` is thing wrapper around [`Moped::Query#count`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Query#count-instance_method). If you look at how `Moped::Query#count` works, [you'll see this](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/1.5.0-stable/lib/moped/query.rb#L35):

```
def count(limit = false)
  command = { count: collection.name, query: selector }
  command.merge!(skip: operation.skip, limit: operation.limit) if limit
  result = collection.database.command(command)
  result["n"].to_i
end
```

So `Moped::Query#count` simply sends a [`count` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/count/) down into MongoDB, then MongoDB does the counting and sends the count back to your Ruby code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very cautious of using mongoid because it's seeming very easy to produce inefficient code. For example, accessing an Object.attribute where .attribute will run a query while in a for loop. Sometimes it's hard to realize that a query is even running because to you it just seems like attribute access.

Comment: That sort of problem happens with all ORMs/ODMs, not just Mongoid/MongoDB. Just wait until you have something that you'd do with a JOIN in SQL.

Comment: I recently encountered this actually. It was a disaster. For each element of results returned from a query on one collection, I had to do a bunch of other queries for other collections which had corresponding "foreign keys". The queries were slow, the work combining objects in ruby was slow. I'm assuming there's a better way-- I just don't know it.

Comment: There are *other* ways but they're just different types of pain. Sometimes you can embed one document in another but then the embedded document has no existence of its own and that causes different problems. The usual "solution" is to denormalize (i.e. keep multiple copies of the same data in different places) and constantly check to ensure that everything is properly synchronized; you are, of course, responsible for making sure all the copies are updated when the master version changes. I find MongoDB to be incredibly difficult to work with for anything non-trivial.